# Carousel com interação touch screen

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, touch

Tenho um carousel que a navegação é atráves das setas right/left.
No mobile, o usuário deve poder "arrastar" o carousel, sem precisar usar as setas para navegar.

Estou usando o carousel do próprio bootstrap.
Preciso de algum framework para ter o resultado desejado?

```html
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
               <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor </p>

           </div>
        </div>
       <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><<</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">>></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sim precisas, pelo menos de JavaScript. Dá uma olhada aqui no site, há muitas perguntas sobre sliders e podes perceber mais sobre o funcionamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indico utilizar um plugin já pronto, como no caso, o [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

**Exemplo:**

HTML:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

  <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage3.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true

      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

  });

});
```

Alem é claro, dos arquivos fornecidos na página.